# Zendframework 3 translation issue

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework3

I am trying to run the Translation module on Zendframework 3, but it does not work for me.

In the module.config.php in the appplication module I have placed the following configuration:

```
'translator' => [
        'locale' => 'de_DE',
        'translation_file_patterns' => [
            [
                'type'     => 'phparray',
                'base_dir' => getcwd() .  '/data/language',
                'pattern'  => 'lang.array.%s.php',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I have my language files in the /data/language folder named lang.array.de.php and lang.array.en.php with the content:

```
return array('All rights reserved' => 'Alle Rechte vorbehalten');
```

and respectively

```
return array('All rights reserved' => 'All rights reserved');
```

I am trying to set the German language in the IndexController of the application module:

```
$translator = new Translator();
        $translator->addTranslationFilePattern('phparray', 'lang.array.de.php', 'lang.array.%s.php', 'en');
        $translator->addTranslationFilePattern('phparray', 'lang.array.en.php', 'lang.array.%s.php', 'de');



$translator->setLocale('de');
```

And in the view script layout.phtmls I have called the translator:

```
<p>&copy; 2016 by Examples Ltd. <?= $this->translate('All rights reserved') ?></p>
```

The main configuration file modules.config.php calls the modules:

```
return [
    'Zend\Paginator',
    'Zend\Navigation',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Zend\I18n',
    'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
    'Application',
    'Album',     
    'Blog',     
];
```

I get no errors when running the application, but the string is not translated too. Please can you revise and help for what is missing in my configuration/calls.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the locale as 'de_DE' instead of 'de' in the controller, like you do now ?

Comment: Locale can set in both ways. It's just value to replace with str_replace. It's folder path most commonly. Checkout if its correct. Also translator checks file with "is_file" and "is_readable". Be sure you have correct right.

Comment: Thank you very much. I placed everywhere - in the locale and in the file name instead of 'de' or 'en' the same string - 'de_DE' and 'en_EN' and it is working. It is working both ways, but it has to be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I have another issue now. I cannot make the strings on the layout.phtml to change dynamically. The layout template seems to be parsed before the module's templates and if I place in the Controller $translator->setLocale('en_EN') it does not affect the layout strings. The module templates are afected, but the layout template gets always the german/the configured in the module.config.php file value. How can I reach the translator in the bootstrap onBootstrap() function of the module? Is there any other way to change the locale dynamically in the layout.phtml?

Comment: İ think you missing something. You are generating translation via config. So it have to affect everything.